# Intuitive presentation of Monodial Category

Tags: intuition, education, monoid, monoidal-categories

I would love to get some feedback from you regarding the following topic:

Imagine you were to introduce monodial categories to youngsters about 17 years of age, in high school, with the common background they get on math.....How would you explain that to them in an intuitive fashion, with nice examples, etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's a "monodial group"?

Comment: Have they seen matrices and matrix multiplication? Because then the category of vector spaces is a nice example.

Comment: I was thinking rather about some phenomenon from our lives that might be modelled like that...something of that sort.....